# How to read a file in Python written out by C++

Tags: python, c++, file-writing, file-read

I have one program written in C++ that outputs the data from several different types of arrays. For simplicity, I'm using ints and just writing them out one at a time to figure this out.

I need to be able to read the file in on Python, but clearly am missing something. I'm having trouble translating the concepts from C++ over to Python.

This is the C++ I have that's working - it writes out two numbers to a file and then reads that file back in (yes, I have to use the ostream.write() and istream.read() functions - that's how at the base level the library I'm using does it and I can't change it).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::ofstream fout;
  std::ifstream fin;

  int outval1 = 1234;
  int outval2 = 5678;

  fout.open("out.txt");
  fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&outval1), sizeof(int));
  fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&outval2), sizeof(int));
  fout.close();
  
  int inval;
  fin.open("out.txt");

  while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&inval), sizeof(int))) {
    std::cout << inval << std::endl;
  }

  fin.close();

  return 0;
}
```

This is what I have on the Python side, but I know it's not correct. I don't think I should need to read in as binary but that's the only way it's working so far

```
with open("out.txt", "rb") as f:
    while (byte := f.read(1)):
        print(byte)
```

Comment: If you want to write the file out as text, maybe use `itoa()` or even just `fprintf`?  Then you can read it in as text on the Python side.

Comment: Those `reinterpret_cast` and `write` and `read` files look very suspect to me. You're lying and saying that `&outval1` is a pointer to a `const char` and saying to write the first `sizeof(int)` many `const char`s from the "array" being pointed to. Which I suppose has the effect of writing out the binary representation of the `int`. But... really, _why_ are you doing it that way to begin with?

Comment: You should open the files in binary mode in this code. It's a must to avoid corruption if you plan to run your program on Windows and just good practice to show intent on other platforms where it doesn't matter as much.

Comment: @NathanPierson that's just how the library is written. It's meant to take in a several different types of values from an array like structure and write them out. I suppose it was written like this to keep it flexible. I couldn't say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simple case you have provided, it is easy to write the Python code to read out 1234 and 5678 (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes) by using [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).
And you should open the file in binary mode.

```py
import sys

with open("out.txt", "rb") as f:
    while (byte := f.read(4)):
        print(int.from_bytes(byte, sys.byteorder))
```

To deal with floats, you may want to try [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```py
import struct


byte = f.read(4)
print(struct.unpack("f", byte)[0])
```

Comment: That ended up working for me. Only thing I'm wondering now is how to do the same thing for floats (output from C++)

Comment: @dave you may have a look at [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)